# Eclipse null analysis raises false positive NullPointerException warning

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, annotations

I am experimenting with Messages classes instead of using hardcoded strings for user displays.  However, I get a `Potential null pointer access:  this expression has a '@Nullable' type` warning from Eclipse (Luna - 4.4.1) with the following code:

In package-info.java:

```
/**
 * My pacakge of tests.
 *
 * @author Flic
 */
@NonNullByDefault
package org.sample;

import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNullByDefault;
```

In Messages.java:

```
package org.sample;

import static java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle;

import java.util.*;
import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.Nullable;

public class Messages
{
  private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "org.sample.messages"; //$NON-NLS-1$
  private static final @Nullable ResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = 
                                                 getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME);

  private Messages()
  {
  }

  public static @Nullable String getString(String key)
  {
    String msgVal = null;
    try
    {
      if (RESOURCE_BUNDLE != null)
        msgVal = RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key);  // Warning on RESOURCE_BUNDLE
    }
    catch (MissingResourceException mrEx)
    {
      msgVal = '!' + key + '!';
    }

    return msgVal;
  }
}
```

The warning goes away if I copy the member variable to a local and check that instead:

```
public static @Nullable String getString(String key)
{
  ResourceBundle checkBundle = RESOURCE_BUNDLE;
  String msgVal = null;

  try
  {
    if (checkBundle != null)
      msgVal = checkBundle.getString(key);  // No warning here
  }
  catch (MissingResourceException mrEx)
  {
    msgVal = '!' + key + '!';
  }

  return msgVal;
}
```

Can anyone explain why the null check on the static final member variable is insufficient to avoid a potential null pointer but assigning its value to a local variable and checking that instead is OK?  Similar checks against String or Integer member variables are fine - this seems to be specific to ResourceBundle objects.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it also flag it if you use `Messages.RESOURCE_BUNDLE`? Also, while not the same situation, they are currently working on [improved flow analysis](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.5/M4/#loop-flows) to remove these kinds of false positives.

Comment: I'm afraid it does, yes.  But thank you for your suggestion.  I'd really like to use annotations, but I don't like being forced to create unnecessary local variables to cover up problems like this.  I wondered if I was missing something obvious, or if this was some kind of bug.

Comment: I think it's a bug, unfortunately. The Eclipse docs recommend creating local variables since it's easier to do the static analysis. You could try out a [build of Eclipse 4.5](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.5M4-201412102000/) and see if it fixes it. Good luck!

Comment: I agree it's a bug.  I just tried the example with the Nullness Checker that is shipped with the Checker Framework (http://checkerframework.org/), and it did not issue the false positive warning.  So you could use that instead of Eclipse's null analysis if you want a more powerful and precise analysis that doesn't force you to degrade your code with unnecessary local variables.  The only downside of the Checker Framework is that its IDE integration is not as slick as that of the Eclipse null analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear this is a bug in Eclipse's nullness checker.  Hopefully this will be addressed in later versions of Eclipse, but I will have a look at the Checker Framework as well.  Thank you to those who have taken a look and made comments.

Comment: The bug in Eclipse has been fixed as of milestone 6 of the upcoming 4.5 release. Note that this example requires "syntactic null analysis for fields" to be enabled, in order to mute some problems relating to concurrency etc.